# Netbeans separted TopComponent in editor mode ignores minimum size

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, netbeans-platform

In my Netbeans 7.11 application I have an additional separated topcomponent in an editor mode that does not respect the minimum size that I specified using the GUI-builder.

The option for "Respect Minimum Size When Resizing Windows" in the Window System tab of the branding is checked.

My .wsmode file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mode PUBLIC
        "-//NetBeans//DTD Mode Properties 2.0//EN"
       "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/mode-properties2_0.dtd">
<mode version="2.0">
    <name unique="myTopComponent" />
    <kind type="view" />
    <state type="separated" />
    <constraints>
        <path orientation="horizontal" number="0" weight="1" />
        <path orientation="vertical" number="0" weight="1" />
    </constraints>
    <bounds x="150" y="150" width="1200" height="670" />
    <frame state="0"/>
    <empty-behavior permanent="true" />
</mode>
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?